# If $X>0$ then $CXC'>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $C \neq 0$ where $X > 0$ means $X$ is positive definite. I have worked out a proof that $X > 0 \Rightarrow CXC' > 0$ but I am not sure whether it is correct. Here it goes:

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be an arbitrary vector and $u=C'v$. Then $v'(CXC')v = (C'v)'X(C'v) = u'Xu$. Since $X>0$, $u'Xu > 0$ which implies $v'(CXC')v > 0$ $\forall v$ then $CXC' > 0$.

Is there any problem with this proof? The reason why I am asking this is that I was also asked to determine the sufficient condition for $CXC' > 0$ given $X>0$, but isn't $X>0$ already the sufficient condition?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What if $C = 0$? Or more generally, what if $C$ is not invertible? On the other hand, what can you say if $C$ is indeed invertible?

Comment: My bad, it is known that $C \neq 0$ but invertibility shouldn't be a problem here? My proof did not require $C$ to be invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v \ne 0$, you can not garantee that $u=C'v \ne 0$.

Example: $n=2$ , $X=I_2$ and $ C=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\\\end{matrix}\right]$.

Then $ CXC'=C$ and $C$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Thank you so much! So the sufficient condition for $CXC’>0$ is that $v$ is not in the null space of $C’$ for all $v \neq 0$, hence $C$ needs to have full rank?